# number of remote messages Giraph

Tags: hadoop, giraph

I am new in Giraph and Hadoop.
Is there any way to count the number of local messages and remote messages (transferred over network) exchanged between vertices of the graph?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the option `giraph.metrics.enable`. This options counts the total amount of messages send in any superstep.